# mysql inner join query where id is obtained from $_GET['id']

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables firm  and contactdetails.  I am trying to get the the firm name from firm and certain contact details from contactdetails.  I am using `$id =$_GET['id'];` to get the id .  In contactdetails i have fk_firm_id which is my foreign key.  I am not sure how to use the inner join query.  I am trying the following query:

```
$sql="SELECT  firm.`name` ,`address_physical_line_1` , `fax_1` , `phone_1` 
FROM contactdetails JOIN firm ON contactdetails.fk_firm_id='$id'";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

but i am not getting the correct firm.  Can anyone help me with this query, please.

Comment: you need to specify a column on join condition,not a value.

Comment: You can not join `var`. You have to define table columns. [Read Document](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: You wouldn't join using `var`. This would just be a `where`

Comment: And once again: mysql_* is deprecated, don't use it. Also don't trust user input, you have to check every variable provided by user. It's good idea to use prepared statements with user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this `JOIN firm ON contactdetails.fk_firm_id = firm.id`

```
$sql=" SELECT  firm.`name` ,`address_physical_line_1` , `fax_1` , `phone_1` 
       FROM    contactdetails 
       JOIN    firm ON contactdetails.fk_firm_id = firm.id
       WHERE   contactdetails.fk_firm_id = '$id'
     ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the WHERE clause that limits the result set to only the firm you're interested in; now you're getting all firms joined with a single contact details record.

```
.. where firm.id=$id
```

For new applications, please use a database API that has prepared statements, like mysqli or pdo.

Comment: You missed to point out the main mistake in the question wrong use of join

Comment: @dianuj, nope, that's not an issue. The way the OP wrote the join is unusual, but it's not wrong. Thanks for correcting the typo though, editing text on a mobile is such a PIA.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that your firm table has a primary key called id

```
 $sql="SELECT  firm.`name` ,`address_physical_line_1` , `fax_1` , `phone_1` FROM contactdetails JOIN firm ON `contactdetails`.`fk_firm_id`=`firm`.`id`
    WHERE `firm`.`id` = '$id'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake about `JOIN` and `WHERE` statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
              f.name,
              c.address_physical_line_1, 
              c.fax_1, 
              c.phone_1 
        FROM 
              contactdetails c JOIN firm f ON c.fk_firm_id= f.id 
        WHERE c.id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT  firm.`name` ,`address_physical_line_1` , `fax_1` , `phone_1` FROM
contactdetails JOIN firm ON contactdetails.fk_firm_id=firm.id where 
contactdetails.fk_firm_id='$id'";
```

you should join on a firm's field such as firm.id

> syntax: FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 compopr
>   table2.field2 compopr is : "=","<",">","<=",">=","<>"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following    query for inner join

```
$sql="SELECT  firm.name ,address_physical_line_1 , fax_1 , phone_1 FROM 
contactctdetails  INNER JOIN firm ON contactdetails.fk_firm_id=$id";
```